# can we limit the number of product in dynamic product Group in shopware 6?

Tags: php, symfony, shopware6

I was trying to generate idealo feed in shopware 6 with 94000 product , it always generate a server timeout ,my best guess is the list is very big that is why it take time ,
I tried to increase my memory and execution time in PHP.ini , but it wont work

so now the Question is can we limit the number of product in Dynamic product Group in the Shopware admin?

Comment: If you're using apache you'll have to set TimeOut to increase execution time as well. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can limit the number of products found by a dynamic product group.

For bigger shops like yours I'd recommend to generate the feed via CLI by checking `Generate via scheduler` in the configuration and create a cron job that runs the `product-export:generate` console command.